# Unable to open the containing app from share menu

Tags: ios8, ios-extensions

I am trying to create a share extension for my app.
 The app is shown in the share menu to share the document, but when i click on my app, the containing app is not called.what should i be doing? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `share view controller` with app group.

http://easynativeextensions.com/how-to-launch-your-app-from-the-ios-8-share-menu/